# IndentationError: expected an indented block python

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скриншоты моего кода,мне сказали что если он скопирован полностью то должен работать,но как видно не работает

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Вы просто ctrl-c ctrl-v сделали?)

Answer (score 0):

У вас там в самом начале программы какая-то заготовка кода, которую вы забыли убрать по типу:

```
def func1():
def func2():
def func3():
...
```

Причём ниже эти же функции нормально реализованы с полноценным телом. Уберите эти заготовки и ошибка должна уйти. Данный код не является корректным кодом питона, потому что функция питона должна иметь тело, начинающееся с отступа. В теле функции может быть другая функция, либо какой-то код, либо хотя бы заменитель кода `pass`, но просто так подряд описать две абсолютно пустых функции питона нельзя.